# Panning with two fingers in Preview (OS X Mavericks)

Tags: preview, macos

Just updated to Mavericks. Has anyone else a scrolling issue in Mavericks?

I used to be able to pan across a page that's zoomed in with two fingers scrolling, but now this same move turns pages, which I can do using keyboard shortcuts more efficiently.

Also, sometimes two fingers scrolling pans accordingly, other times it turns page. I can't figure out a consistent behavior (scrolling on the side of the trackpad doesn't work).

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I am having this problem. It appears to be a [known problem](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=310649) with both Chrome and Firefox. So far, I've only seen this behavior in these two browsers. It does not appear to affect Safari.

There are posts from as early as August indicating that this was an issue.

Several posts have suggested [clearing your Mac's PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379) as a temporary fix, as well as turning off the "two finger swipe to switch pages" gesture for both Mouse and Trackpad.

Comment: Thank you! The problem occurred on a 2011 MBA but it doesn't seem to occur on the latest 15" rMBP. Though it'd be strange if it were a hardware-related issue.

Comment: PRAM? Not everyone (count me in) knows what that means.